# How to read scorecard items programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint, ssas, performancepoint

I managed to get the scorecard item using the BIMonitoringAuthoringServiceProxy webservice, but I have no idea how can i go through the items that it holds (am unsure of the terminology that should be used for the items that are shown in the scorecard).

I need to read these values and draw them on a bing map, so i need to iterate through the items.

I couldn't find any references online. So any help guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't seen this, this topic describes the high-level scorecard architecture -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557351.aspx

Not sure if this will help with what you are trying to do, but this is a sample of looping through a scorecard object that is used by scorecard transforms: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb833673.aspx)

```
// Get the headers under the root row header.
List<GridHeaderItem> nonLeafRowHeaders = viewData.RootRowHeader.GetAllHeadersInTree();

// Get the leaf headers under the root column header.
List<GridHeaderItem> leafColumnHeaders = viewData.RootColumnHeader.GetAllLeafHeadersInTree();

foreach (GridHeaderItem rowHeader in nonLeafRowHeaders)
{
    foreach (GridHeaderItem columnHeader in leafColumnHeaders)
    {
        // Get scorecard cells.
        GridCell cell = viewData.Cells[rowHeader, columnHeader];

        if (cell.IsCellEmpty || string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.ActualValue.ToString()))
        {
            //do something with cell
        }
        viewData.Cells[rowHeader, columnHeader] = cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man.. That did work!
Do you know how to filter the scorecard programmatically using the mdx filter expression?